# Define OCaml-style type variants in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to `Scala` but have some experience in using `OCaml` and some other ML family functional programming languages.

I am wondering how could I define the `OCaml` style type variants? For example,

```
type fruit = Apple | Orange | Strawberry
let analysis f = 
   match f with
   | Apple -> ...
   | Orange -> ...
   | Strawberry -> ...
```

I am sorry if this question is too naive.. Hope someone can help me on that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384189/type-to-capture-either-integer-float-or-a-string-value-and-then-do-pattern-matc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know OCaml, but it looks like you're trying to do something like this.

```
sealed abstract class Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class Orange extends Fruit
class Strawberry extends Fruit

def mixFruit(f: Fruit) = f match {
  case a: Apple =>      // do something with a
  case o: Orange =>     // do something with o
  case s: Strawberry => // do something with s
}
```

Comment: For this case it's rather `object Apple`, etc.